# .htaccess mod rewrite only with certain domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website `www.website.com` and a few domains that redirect to this site. It's a masked redirect, so if I write `www.domain.com` I can see this url in the browser all the time, but it's actually redirected to `subdomain.website.com` What I'd like to do is do some `.htaccess` rewrite rule, so that everything that has domain `domain.com` will be rewrited to a local file on a server, that is outside of current folder. Let me explain folder structure here:

```
/
sub/
-- subdomain/
-- test/
---- index.html
web/
```

Currently everything from `www.domain.com` goes to `/sub/subdomain`. In the .`htaccess` file in `/sub/subdomain` I want to reroute the request to `/sub/test/index.html`. So in my `.htaccess` file in `sub/subdomain` folder I've tried this:

```
#start masked redirect
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .. /test/index.html [L]
#end masked redirect 


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Yes, I'm doing all this on top of Wordpress, which I don't really believe matters, but just to be sure I'm posting it.

Unfortunatelly I get `Internal Server Error 500`

What am I doing wrong, please?

Also: Please don't ask me why I am doing it like this, it has a reason, I'm not uncovering the whole thing I'm trying to do as it is irrelevant to this problem and I really want to focus on this issue here. I just want to know how to fix my .htaccess and it has to be this way. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Is WP installed in DOCUMENT_ROOT or somewhere else?

Comment: WP is installed in the /sub/subdomain folder

Comment: Basically I'm trying to avoid using WP using .htaccess on one special case when there is one concrete domain used

Comment: So every request for `subdomain.website.com` should be forwarded to `/sub/test/index.html` and completely skip WP for this `subdomain.website.com`?

Answer (score 0):

This should be in `sub/subdomain/.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^test/index\.html$ /test/index.html [L,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: this unfortunatelly didn't work. First of all my RewriteCond is correct. But that wouldn't be a problem I changed that, the problem is though the path in RewriteRule and I still get the 500 error

Comment: well for www.domain.com

Comment: thanks for your effort, but the error log is not helpfull, it says that limit of recursive redirects is exceeded, but that is clearly only a side effect of paths being set wrong. And that's really what my question is all about. I only don't know how to fix my paths

Comment: ok, RewriteCond should be on domain.com, not subdomain(but I've got that covered). And next -> I think somewhere should be stated, that folder "test" is not within my subdomain folder (as you'll see by inspecting the folder structure that I've described in the question). I tried to write something like "sub/test/index.html" or "../test/index.html" but these didn't work. I'll try to find and ask someone IRL so that he can directly try it with me. Thanks for trying to help, though.